# Top performance problems in Jboss AS 7

Tags: jboss, transactions, ejb, jboss7.x, application-server

I've taken part in a project where we have recently changed the application server to Jboss AS 7 (EAP 6). The system is a Jboss installation running in Domain Mode with one server (Server A) containing EJB's connecting to a relational database and the other (Server B) being a front-end node primaraly with JSP's connecting to Server A.

Before starting our load and performance testing I though I would ask here.

Question:

> What are the major pitfalls and performance tweaks needed on a Jboss
>   AS 7 (EAP 6) in Domain Mode running a mix of transactional EJB's and JSP
>   web-interfaces?

Comment: Why are you separating the JSP layer from the EJB layer ? Surely you will get better performance having them co-located in the same JVM.

Answer (score 5):

The top performance problem is typically separating EJB beans and UI code on separate servers.

This pattern was advocated in 2001 because the concept "distributed objects" just sounded cool at the time.

After many failed and dog slow IT projects, people started thinking: why on earth do we put a slow network between two arbitrary pieces of code? What do we win?

The answer was invariably; nothing much if anything at all.

Long story short; don't put Servlets, JSP pages and JSF Servlets on a different server. Put your EJBs in the same EAR or even consider just putting them in the same war (just create a package "business").

Answer (score -1):

One of top performance contributors in our JBoss 7 project was the fact that the server was not fine tuned, i.e. by default it runs many unused and unneeded service. These services affect almost all aspects of application life cycle, such as deployment speed, responsiveness, memory and disk footprint.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is basically my question. You haven't really given any concrete response at all.